# How to implement ordering, paging and filtering with too many tables?

Tags: mysql

There is an user info query service. The details of each user are from 5 Mysql tables. Ordering, paging and filtering are needed. It is easy to implement with one single SQL.
Like this:

```
SELECT A.a,B.b,C.c,D.d,E.e 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.biz_id=B.biz_id 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.biz_id=C.biz_id 
LEFT JOIN D ON A.biz_id=D.biz_id 
LEFT JOIN E ON A.biz_id=E.biz_id 
WHERE A.a = $a 
  AND B.b = $b 
  AND C.c = $c 
  AND D.d = $d 
  AND E.e = $e 
ORDER BY E.create_time,
         D.status 
LIMIT 0,10
```

But there is a rule by DBA that the online query SQL should has **no more than 3 JOIN**s. So I must get all data from database, and then do ordering, paging and filtering in application, that is impossible with too many records.

Ordering, paging and filtering with big data is a common problem.
Is there any practical solutions?

Comment: Just get a new DBA.

Comment: Incidentally, all of your JOINs are INNER JOINs

Comment: You could utilize a VIEW - so the online query will contain no JOINS at all. But still, consider getting a new DBA.

Comment: Your DBA does not know what they are doing.